# Android Justify spanable Text-view that support RTL Languages

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left, spannablestring, text-justify

I need to create a custom **text-view** in android, first of all it should be **justified**, then it should support **spans** and although it should support **RTL** (Right to Left) languages for ex: Farsi (Persian) ,...

I'm working on this issue for a week! but In fact I stuck In a bad condition because non of available libraries support all these conditions ( **Justify**, **Spanable**, **RTL**)

***Do you have any idea***?!

---

I although checked lots of libraries for ex:  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: I have same problem too!

Comment: Attribute "android:textDirection" is available but can be only used in API level 17 or above.[Here is the link](http://androidsbs.blogspot.in/2013/11/androidtextdirection.html)

Comment: Hi Hamid - try it : https://github.com/Saleh-Hassan/RTL-TextJustify-Android

Comment: Hi Saeid - this library does not support Span

Comment: for span check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for my rtl textView :

```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            textView.setJustificationMode(LineBreaker.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
        }else {
            textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [this](https://github.com/Saleh-Hassan/RTL-TextJustify-Android).

The package was created specifically for Right-ToLeft and Justified Textviews, and should support Spannable since it is an extension of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

how to justify span **RTL** `TextView` ?

First use this library [RTL-TextJustify-Android](https://github.com/Saleh-Hassan/RTL-TextJustify-Android)

Then before setting text to the `TextView` :

```
 TextViewEx = myJustifiedTextView;
 myJustifiedTextView = findViewById...........;


 finalDescription = "";

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        finalDescription = Html.fromHtml(SpanTextHere, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString();
    } else {
        finalDescription = Html.fromHtml(SpanTextHere).toString();
    }

myJustifiedTextView.setText(finalDescription,true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file and change your apps "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end".

Refer [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) link for more information.