# Can't import images in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-drawable

As normally in android studio images are imported by dragging and dropping into the Drawable folder, I am unable to do it. It doesn't allow me to drop the image into that folder.
Plz help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your image in windows, then press ctrl + c OR Right click and
   Copy
2. Go to Your res Folder And choose One of the folders(eg. MDPI,
       HDPI..) and press ctrl + v OR right click it and Paste

Comment: thanx @harshad pansuriya it help me.

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you. then make it accept so other people help also.