# Text justification in android

Tags: android, textview, justify

I know that this question have been asked previously. Some are:

[Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

[Can I set property of Textview like justify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976627/can-i-set-property-of-textview-like-justify)

But after passing some years(!) there is no good solution for this. Using third-party libraries is not a good solution hence they are not working accurate and even worse, using them makes your app works slow.

Even with a two up votes, this question have never got an answer:

[Android Text Justification in TextView (NOT WebView) Without Third Party Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737713/android-text-justification-in-textview-not-webview-without-third-party-library)

So, my question is, how come something this much common, useful, necessary and simple thing is not solved by google??? Isn't there a good solution after passing this much time? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend standart TextView and overwrite onTextChanged method.
Than you need implement justify. What i'm currently do.

If you are lucky, you will able to implement your own component :)

For use it you can just specify full package name of your class in your xml layout.

Please keep this thread updateable.

Comment: You can share what have you done and let us make it better together.

Comment: Ones it's done yes sure :)
Unfortunatelly it isn't my main project.