# Justify text in textview

Tags: android, html, textview, android-textattributes

I have string in resources I want to do justification on that so that it could look good and easy to read. But Sadly Android does not support the justification straight away.  To do some justification I am doing some researches and found the way to use the **Html.fromHtml** to justify the text.

But sadly I do not know How to use it. To me justification is not working I am setting it as follows

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2 align=right>Android</h2><br><p \"align=justify\">Sdasndakdnsakdnsakdnsandkasndasda adabdkjasbdkasj sadaskjdnksajdn asdnsadknas" +
                    "asjkdbaskdja asodnsakjdnas asdjasndsad alsdnasldnasl ansd dj jasdoa nqowdjnl hjd l  dpajpa ajop p adpjasiojdiosjaodj a sjdas nd op apjpdja apjdoajpj aldoapjdap pajdpajdpajpd " +
                    "asdasidnsalkdnsalkdaskldsalkdnlksadm" +
                    "asdksandlksadnlsakmdlskadksald" +
                    "asdnkasndlksandlksamdlsakdna" +
                    "asdlkasndlkasndksnakldnsa" +
                    "asdansldknsalkdnsalkdn</p>"));
```

> i just put the demo text. No matter what Ever I put into the tag it
>   alwasy comes with the left alignment.

**Right now you can see I have used align=justify**

So please kindly guide me How can justify my text.

> **Note :** I do not want to center align my text . I just want to use the
>   Justification

Comment: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Comment: `fromHTML()` suports only small subset of html tags. Justification is not supported and you must either use WebView, or some of existing libraries supporting justification

Comment: Do you want right align?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski can you please give me link of good and updated library link

Comment: @BalaRaja I want to justify my text

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<h2 align=right>Android</h2><br><p align=justify>Sdasndakdnsakdnsakdnsandkasndasda adabdkjasbdkasj sadaskjdnksajdn asdnsadknas" +
                "asjkdbaskdja asodnsakjdnas asdjasndsad alsdnasldnasl ansd dj jasdoa nqowdjnl hjd l  dpajpa ajop p adpjasiojdiosjaodj a sjdas nd op apjpdja apjdoajpj aldoapjdap pajdpajdpajpd " + 
                "asdasidnsalkdnsalkdaskldsalkdnlksadm" + 
                "asdksandlksadnlsakmdlskadksald" + 
                "asdnkasndlksandlksamdlsakdna" + 
                "asdlkasndlkasndksnakldnsa" + 
                "asdansldknsalkdnsalkdn</p>]]>"));
```

Basically you need to put your text indide CDATA as above for it to be formatted as an html

Comment: and its giving me error , I think you have made the typo error or braces error

Comment: it is showing all data as it is , and even including the  tag of H2 aling = right till align = justify

Comment: Just try the edited code, see the thing is that CDATA is the way to make your text be read as an HTML. I am not running this code so making syntax errors is expected. I will post below how I had used CDATA, maybe that will help you.

Comment: This is how I used it: <string name="offline_digest_footer">If you are not making a transaction or for help please contact us at <![CDATA[<b><font color=#00bcd4>1-800</font></b>]]></string>    footer.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.offline_digest_footer)));

Comment: you used this in resources ?

Comment: yes, I added the string with the html to the string resouces and then read it as html. Also did you try the edited code above?

Comment: ya I tried and it is showing me the tags in the text as well

Comment: try using escape characters for the tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105117/discussion-between-sid-and-allay-khalil).

Comment: Not yet, seems like complete justification for textView in android is not possible. The ways to do it are not very straightforward. You can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text . I will keep trying, if I find somthing, will comment here.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this without resorting to html using `android:gravity` in a `TextView`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Your text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Available gravity options are shown in [the docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)