# How to make text fill whole line of TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView that Im using as row format for ListView. I want that the texts in those TextViews fill whole line.
My text format is like this:
XXX STORE NAME X (X are numbers) 
I want to make the line as

```
-XXX STORE NAME X-
-XXX STR NAME   X-
-XXX STRE NM   XX-
```

something like `setw()` in c++

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done with standard attributes, but you can use [3d party library](https://github.com/merterhk/JustifiedTextView).

Also you can try [some hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899082/5766983).