# Error inflating class ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I'm going to have a `justified textview` with Persian language and most of the this [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text) link solution wasn't really helpful except one of it's solution that was this link https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView.
i implement the code like this but  Unable to start activity ComponentInfo and it's says that `Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView  need to be inflated` but how can i inflate this.

this is my code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android.justify;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private JustifiedTextView mJTv;
    private TextView mTv;
    private SeekBar mSbSize;
    private LinearLayout mLlGreen, mLlRed;
    private TextView mTvEng, mTvFa;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }
    private void initViews() {
        mJTv = (JustifiedTextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_jtv);
        mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tv);
        mLlGreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_ll_green);
        mLlRed = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_ll_red);
        mTvEng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tv_eng);
        mTvFa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tv_fa);

        mSbSize = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_sb_size);
        mSbSize.setMax(20);
        mSbSize.setProgress(10);

      /*  mSbSize.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        mLlGreen.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLlRed.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTvEng.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTvFa.setOnClickListener(this);*/
    }
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int pos, boolean arg2) {

        int size = 10;
        mTv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, pos + size);
        mJTv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, pos + size);
        mJTv.setLineSpacing(pos - size);
        mTv.setLineSpacing(pos - size, 1);
    }
}
```

and  i added JustifiedTextView as a class and also XmlToClassAttribHandler

class that he also said to add it is here:

```
package com.example.android.justify;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;

public class XmlToClassAttribHandler {
    private Resources mRes;
    private Context mContext;
    private AttributeSet mAttributeSet;

    private String namespace="http://noghteh.ir";
    private final String KEY_TEXT="text";
    private final String KEY_TEXT_SIZE="textSize";
    private final String KEY_TEXT_COLOR="textColor";

    public XmlToClassAttribHandler(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
        mContext=context;
        mRes=mContext.getResources();
        mAttributeSet=attributeSet;


    }

    public String getTextValue(){

        String value=mAttributeSet.getAttributeValue(namespace, KEY_TEXT);

        if (value==null)
            return "";

        if (value.length()>1 &&
                value.charAt(0)=='@' &&
                value.contains("@string/")){
            int resId=mRes.getIdentifier(mContext.getPackageName()+":"+value.substring(1), null,null);
            value=mRes.getString(resId);
        }

        return value;

    }

    public int getColorValue(){

        String value=mAttributeSet.getAttributeValue(namespace, KEY_TEXT_COLOR);

        int color= Color.BLACK;

        if (value==null)
            return color;

        if (value.length()>1 &&
                value.charAt(0)=='@' &&
                value.contains("@color/")){
            int resId=mRes.getIdentifier(mContext.getPackageName()+":"+value.substring(1), null,null);
            color=mRes.getColor(resId);

            return color;
        }


        try{
            color=Color.parseColor(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return Color.BLACK;
        }


        return color;
    }


    public int getTextSize() {
        int textSize=12;

        String value=mAttributeSet.getAttributeValue(namespace, KEY_TEXT_SIZE );

        if (value==null)
            return textSize;

        if (value.length()>1 &&
                value.charAt(0)=='@' &&
                value.contains("@dimen/")){
            int resId=mRes.getIdentifier(mContext.getPackageName()+":"+value.substring(1), null,null);
            textSize=mRes.getDimensionPixelSize(resId);

            return textSize;
        }

        try{
            textSize=Integer.parseInt(value.substring(0, value.length()-2));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return 12;
        }

        return textSize;
    }


    public int gettextSizeUnit() {

        String value=mAttributeSet.getAttributeValue(namespace, KEY_TEXT_SIZE );

        if (value==null)
            return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP;

        try{
            String type=value.substring(value.length()-2, value.length());

            if (type.equals("dp"))
                return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP;
            else if (type.equals("sp"))
                return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP;
            else if (type.equals("pt"))
                return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT;
            else if (type.equals("mm"))
                return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM;
            else if (type.equals("in"))
                return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN;
            else if (type.equals("px"))
                return TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return -1;
        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

and this is the error that i got:

```
06-19 19:52:01.757 11580-11580/com.example.android.justify E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.justify/com.example.android.justify.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                                 at com.example.android.justify.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                                 at com.example.android.justify.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it's seems that the error says i need to inflate `ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView` but how should i have to do it

and main activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_1"
        android:text="JustifiedTextView:"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/gray_2" >

        <ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView
            xmlns:noghteh="http://noghteh.ir"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_jtv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="25dp"
            noghteh:text="@string/text_fa"
            noghteh:textColor="@color/red"
            noghteh:textSize="20sp" >
        </ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_1"
        android:text="Default TextView:"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/gray_2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="25dp"
            android:text="@string/text_fa"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_sb_size"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </SeekBar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_ll_green"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_ll_red"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv_fa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="FA" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv_eng"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="EN" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post xml code of textview...

Comment: I just edited the post. the error is exactly on  <ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView xml tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_1"
        android:text="JustifiedTextView:"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/gray_2" >

        <com.example.android.justify.JustifiedTextView
            xmlns:noghteh="http://noghteh.ir"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_jtv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="25dp"
            noghteh:text="@string/text_fa"
            noghteh:textColor="@color/red"
            noghteh:textSize="20sp" >
        </com.example.android.justify.JustifiedTextView>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_1"
        android:text="Default TextView:"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/gray_2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="25dp"
            android:text="@string/text_fa"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_sb_size"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </SeekBar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_ll_green"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_ll_red"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv_fa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="FA" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv_eng"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="EN" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can easily add changes. not the whole layout. it is not useful to others