# Allign text of a TextView within a ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I am displaying a large block of text in a `TextView` within a `ScrollView` like [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI4ov.png).

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/date_text"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explenation_text"
        android:text="@string/explanation_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

Would there be a way to have my text aligned to the right, therefore to have one block of text without varying line sizes?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is Justify Block of Text inside a `Textview`...

Here what i found when i face this problem:

1. Android do not supports full justification. see this [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)
2. you can use `Gravity` but it will not solve your problem in every case
   `gravity` attribute specifies how to align the text inside the `TextView` `layout_gravity` specifies how to align/layout the `TextView` element itself.
3. You can use `webview` to align a block of text in your layout
   http://www.seal.io/2010/12/only-way-how-to-align-text-in-block-in.html
4. There are some open source library which you can use to justify your `Textview` text

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView