# Android O Text Justification Hebrew

Tags: android, textview, android-8.0-oreo

I know there has been A LOT of talk here regarding justifying text in Android. But Android O just came out and a new feature came out with it, Text Justification. They say use the final `JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD` included with the `TextView` class. Along with `setJustificationMode()`. it does work when I use it with the English language, but it fails to work when I use it with the Hebrew language. I have it set up to:

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:justificationMode="inter_word"
            android:text="@string/ahahvaRabba"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            />
```

I also tried to put `android:gravity="right"` but that didnt work either.
I cant imagine that google didn't think of using it with other languages.

Comment: It's a new feature, so there are likely to be teething problems. I've tried using it myself and I've discovered that if you set a link movement method (so that <a> tags in your text work) it turns off the justification. I think I'll submit that as a bug report and see what they say...

Comment: Hey, I realized that my mistake was that I was using the feature on a device that was android m and it really wasn't working because of that. Do you know if theres a way to make it work on previous android firmwares?

Comment: Mainly for the reason I mentioned, I've fallen back to using the solution provided by twiceYuan for all versions of Android, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text/43818960#43818960  I did make a couple of tweaks to it though and I don't know if you'll be able to adapt it for rtl text. The other solution that probably makes the most sense is to just use a web view, although for me that seems a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.