# how to align text width in a Textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, text, textview, android-xml

I want to align text in My `TextView` like this

[image]

and my current appearance of `textView` is like

[image]

How can I achieve `text layout` without using `Webview`

Comment: show your xml file @ShoaibAnwar

Comment: Checkout [this link](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android), it might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: try this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-how-to-display-information-with-justify-alignment/

Answer (score 3):

`TextView` in Android O offers full justification (new typographic alignment) itself.

You just need to do this,

```
textView.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
default is JUSTIFICATION_MODE_NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Install Just add to your **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
}
```

or

use : https://github.com/Saleh-Hassan/RTL-TextJustify-Android

Example:

[image]

[image]