# How to Justify the text and align properly in textview in android

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have one `TextView` in `xml`, but am giving the `TextView` values in java.while displaying its not proper alignment.Please can you give solution.

In `Xml` i give the values means it's displaying properly,but in java i am giving values its not showing in proper way.I want to justify the text

```
    <TextView 
    android:text="" android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="left|center|right" 
    android:gravity="left|center|right" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textAlignment="center" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Comment: please share java code

Comment: <TextView android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/result"
                    
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_gravity="left|center|right"
                    android:gravity="left|center|right"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

Comment: not in here, in your question

Comment: How to alignment set in java code.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/pouriaHemmati/JustifiedTextView

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add this code

```
 android:justificationMode="inter_word"
```

Answer (score 5):

Android 0 supports justification of TextView. Please follow the below link

- [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text/42991773#42991773)

You can also use below library for Text Justfication.

- https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your solution.Its working fine.I cant able to accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for your solution.I posted another issue.Can you please help me to fix the issue.am running cordova ionic project folder in android