# Justification below Android O

Tags: android, textview

I see above API 26 there is a method for justify textviews.

```
android:justificationMode="inter_word"
```

Is there a solution for lower API levels?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: It is neither duplicate nor it needs to be more focused. I think this is a valid and proper question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a library for this. I do not see a way to do it without. The support-library got some support for justification recently. Not sure about inter_word though. There are also 3rd party libs like https://github.com/programingjd/justified