# Android. TextView doesn't wrap properly

Tags: android

I have my text as "wrap_content" and another `View` behind it which extends to the limits of the `TextView`.

Is there a way to make it wrap properly? In case of a text which needs an escape to a second line, it'll max out the width of the `TextView` in its parent and then escape the text, but it won't readjust the width to remove the white space which is left behind, as you can see below.

i.e. what I would like to happen is the right side of the background come closer to the word `Write` and not leave that much amount of space there.

[image]

In case of single line text, everything looks fine.

[image]

Any ideas on how to wrap the text better?

**EDIT**

```
//....
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/list_item_bot_avatar"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <!--ANIMATED CONTAINER-->
    <com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_bot_card"
        style="@style/BotTextMsgCardBot">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_bot_typing_animation"
            style="@style/BotTextMsgTypingAnim" />

    </com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView>

    <!--TEXT-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_bot_msg"
        style="@style/BotTextMsgTextBot" />

</RelativeLayout>
//....
```

and

```
<style name="BotTextMsgCardBot" parent="BotTextMsgCard">
    <item name="optRoundCardBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="BotTextMsgCardUser" parent="BotTextMsgCard">
    <item name="optRoundCardBackgroundColor">#28A8E0</item>
</style>

<style name="BotTextMsgTypingAnim">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">5dp</item>
    <item name="lottie_autoPlay">true</item>
    <item name="lottie_fileName">bot_typing.json</item>
    <item name="lottie_loop">true</item>
</style>

<style name="BotTextMsgTextBot" parent="BotTextMsgText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="BotTextMsgText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/bot_messages_horiz_spacing_x2</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/bot_messages_horiz_spacing_x2</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/bot_general_elevation</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="key">ignore</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<dimen name="bot_general_elevation">3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="bot_messages_horiz_spacing">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="bot_messages_horiz_spacing_x2">25dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Can I see your code?

Comment: Can you post your xml code?

Comment: What have you done for this?

Comment: See edit, please

Comment: Also send the values of BotTextMsgCard, bot_messages_horiz_spacing_x2, bot_general_elevation.

Comment: Done. See edit.

Comment: think you want to justify textview. checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't want the TEXT to "stretch" to the width of it's container, i want the CONTAINER to "squish" to the width of the text and not leave unnecessary white spaces. So, somewhat the other way around, I guess.