# androidX AppCompatTextView justificationMode

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, androidx

I know, the question may seem duplicate but is not. I am using `AppCompatTextView` from `androidX` and the documentation says that the `AppCompatTextView` inherits the `TextView`'s long list of methods. Among them there is `setJustificationMode()` and `getJustificationMode()` methods. But still I can't use those methods below API 26.

```
@BindView(R.id.textView3) AppCompatTextView mTextView;

@Override
public void prepareUI() {
    mTextView.setJustificationMode(Layout.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
}
```

I even tried writing it from the XML, but still no success. 
I tried it with `app:justificationMode` && `android:justificationMode`...
Is there something that I am doing it wrong or missing?

Here is the link to the `AppCompatTextView` documentation:
[AppCompatTextView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView)

Comment: it looks like method you are using is not inherited in androidx see this. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView

Comment: JustificationModes are only used on Android Oreo and above not below that..

Comment: Android does not support "Full Justification", but ....
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24986794/3941761