# How to aligne 2 words in textview one left and second right

Tags: java, android, textview

Does anyone know how to aligne two numbers on one line in android textview so one is aligned left and second one right?
Gravity doesnt help neither html.format...[image]
Btw:i need to be able to keep changing properties of the text like colors etc..

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is supported by android. Maybe using justify could do it, but it only works on Oreo and beyond

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293541/3885877

Else I would try a custom text view, where the 2 texts are aligned to the sides.

But I don't think you can achieve this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

So i solve it by adding second textview

Answer (score -1):

You could use dynamic strings with strings.value for this.
For example:
in strings.xml add this:

```
<string name="left_and_right_alignment">%1$s %2$s</string>
```

and in your class you can use:

```
getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.left_and_right_alignment, "left", "right")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm thank you for try but your solution is not what i was looking for. Doesnt work at all

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem