# Justify align text in static layout?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I JUSTIFY align text in a static layout programmatically? Thanks for your time.

I only see the following options for `staticLayout.setAlignment()`:

```
Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER
Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL
Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you actually want to do with the `TextView` alignment?

Comment: @MojoJojo I added an illustration. I want the second effect. JUSTIFIED

Comment: Did you try  [setJustificationMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setJustificationMode(int)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it like `textView.justificationMode = JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD`. But it requires Android O (Api level 26).

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42991773/19115089

Another option would be to try a third party library like https://github.com/mathew-kurian/TextJustify-Android (but no longer maintained)